# Reduce loading time of web page

Tags: php, yii

I need to display all students detail in the table format while clicking the "Print" link in my web page. Users may print these records in this page. It may have several thousands of records.

Because of this, it took more time to load. Is it possible to load records page by page? Or am i need to do any other thing to reduce the loading time?

Please advice.

Note: I have optimized my code as much as possible as per the Google search.

Comment: Use cachegrind to pinpoint bottleneck. Also check if bottleneck is on server side or client side. If on client, optimize css, minimize event handlers etc.

Comment: Printing several thousands of records?  How many records per page? Will the user actually use the ream of paper needed to print it?  And will it be used for something other than archive? Any more it seems that when more than a handful of pages are printed, the users never look at the report, it just goes in a file cabinet somewhere. If it is printed in the first place. Maybe producing a spreadsheet that can be downloaded would work better.

Answer (score 0):

I would install wkhtmltopdf, I would use a html template, then generate a pdf file using the html template when changes are made to the list, and download that file when needed.

This way, you save processing power, and the users download the same file.

Also, by doing so, most browsers know how to render a pdf file without downloading it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using [CPagination class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination)

You have an example in that Doc page.

You will have to paginate the records, if they are in DB, Yii will instruct the db engine to only retrieve the records in a range, making it efficiently.

Comment: He want to **print** entire list, pagination does not fit here

Comment: @PeterM "Because of this, it took more time to load. Is it possible to load records page by page?"

Comment: Well, thats right, but pressing print, then next page, then print and so on? Seems weird.

Comment: He might want to print a page per time.... other way the question should be clearer.